# C# Making an Async Call Synchronously

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

I have a library that only allows for Async calls, my code needs to be synchronous. Will the following code work correctly? Can anyone foresee any problems with it?

```
RestResponse<T> response = null;
bool executedCallBack = false;
client.ExecuteAsync(request, (RestResponse<T> aSyncResponse)=>{
    executedCallBack = true;
    response = aSyncResponse;
});

while (!executedCallBack){
    Thread.Sleep(100);
}
..continue execution synchronously
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't poll.  Use the built-in synchronization facilities.

```
RestResponse<T> response = null;
var executedCallBack = new AutoResetEvent(false);
client.ExecuteAsync(request, (RestResponse<T> aSyncResponse)=>{
    response = aSyncResponse;
    executedCallBack.Set();
});

executedCallBack.WaitOne();
//continue execution synchronously
```

As a side note, I had to switch the order of operations inside the callback.  Your example had a race condition, since the flag could allow the main thread to continue, and try to read the response, before the callback thread had written it.

Answer (score 2):

Usually async calls return you some sort of token (e.g. [IAsyncResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iasyncresult.aspx)) which lets you just wait for it, without polling. Does your API not do that at all?

Another option is to use `ManualResetEvent` or `Monitor.Wait`/`Pulse` instead of the sleep loop.

Comment: No, I do not get an IAsyncResult. Whats the difference between ManualResetEvent and AutoResetEvent below?

Comment: For one-shot use, there is no difference.  A `ManualResetEvent` remains in the "set" state until you call `Reset()`, whereas an `AutoResetEvent` automatically resets after unblocking one waiting thread.  Usually this is what you want.  I only use `ManualResetEvent`s when I specifically want to allow multiple waiting threads (or successive waits by the same thread) to be released.